# Xamarin.Forms how do I access a public function from another CS file?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So I'm new to XF and I'm wondering about `AppState`/`Activity` life cycle on Android. 
The code directly below this is in a file called `test.xaml.cs`.

How the sound works is you can say something like `startSound.Play()` or `startSound.Stop()` to start or stop sound in the app. I have noticed a bug that doesn't stop sound when the rest of the app resets via the back button (even though it's held in memory?)

```
public Test()
    {
        startSound = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        startSound.Load(Path.Combine($"Audio", "startBeep.wav"));

        stopSound = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        stopSound.Load(Path.Combine($"Audio", "stopBeep.wav"));

        winSound = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        winSound.Load(Path.Combine($"Audio", "winBeep.wav"));

        endSound = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        endSound.Load(Path.Combine($"Audio", "endBeep.wav"));

        addSound = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
        addSound.Load(Path.Combine($"Audio", "addBeep.wav"));
    }
```

What I would like to do is in the `app.xaml.cs` file to go into protected `override void OnSleep()` and write `startSound.stop();` so that the sound stops whenever the app sleeps. However I do not know how to access the public function of `Test` in `test.xaml.cs`.

This is the code line for `app.xaml.cs`

```
protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("OnSleep");
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }
```

I've used the debug to make sure that the app state changes so I know the `OnSleep()` works properly.

Comment: You can try this  `var  startSound = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
          startSound.Stop();`

Comment: Look out Dependency Injection or MessagingService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to accomplish that.

> Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter enables view models and other components to communicate with without having to know anything about each other besides a simple Message contract.

Just send a message in the `OnSleep` of your `App` and subscribe to the message on your `Test`:

In your OnSleep:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<App>(this, "OnSleep");
```

In your Test:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>(this, "OnSleep", (sender) => {
    startSound.stop(); 
});
```

HIH

Comment: great, I'm glad. Could you accept the answer please?